# Converting if/else to ternary operator

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I'm just getting to grips with ternary operators in PHP and am having trouble converting the following:

```
<? if( $link['file'] ): ?>
  <?=$link['file'] ?>
<? else: ?>
  <?=$link['link'] ?>
<? endif ?>
```

My attempt so far, that generates an error:

```
<? if( $link['file'] ) ? $link['file'] : $link['link']; ?>
```

Any pointers how to get this conversion working, it must be close?

Thanks

Comment: `<? $link['file']  ? $link['file'] : $link['link']; ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With shorthand form `?:`

```
<?= $link['file'] ?: $link['link'] ?>
```

Full form:

```
<?= $link['file'] ? $link['file'] : $link['link'] ?>
```

Comment: If it's php 7, you could also do a <?= $link['file'] ?? $link['link'] ?>, which is better because you won't have a notice if $link['file'] is not set.